# Unexpected result in Depth First Search

Tags: python, graph-algorithm

I am implementing a graph class and would like to write a function that determines whether a given path exists.

My graph is represented as {a:{b:c}} where a and b are a vertex connected to each other, and c is the weight of the edge. **It is a non-directional graph. I'd like to implement my does_path_exist() function for a non-directional graph.** It currently computes as if my graph is directional.

Given:

```
{0: {1: 5.0, 2: 10.0}, 1: {3: 3.0, 4: 6.0}, 3: {2: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0}, 4: {6: 6.0}, 5: {6: 2.0}, 7: {9: 1.0}, 8: {7: 2.0, 9: 4.0}}
```

A path exists from vertex 2 to 3. Since my function is direction oriented, it returns False.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        """
        Constructor
        :param n: Number of vertices
        """
        self.order = n
        self.size = 0
        self.vertex = {}

    def insert_edge(self, u, v, w): #works fine
        if u in self.vertex and v < self.order:
            if not v in self.vertex[u]:
                self.vertex[u][v] = w
                self.size += 1
        elif u not in self.vertex and u < self.order and v < self.order:
            self.vertex[u] = {}
            self.vertex[u][v] = w
            self.size += 1
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def does_path_exist(self, u, v): #works for directed graph, but not non-directed graph
        if u >= self.order or v >= self.order:
            raise IndexError
        if u == v:
            return True
        stac = []
        stac.append(u)
        visited = []
        while len(stac) != 0:
            u = stac.pop(0)
            if u not in visited:
                if u == v:
                    return True
                visited.append(u)
                if u in self.vertex:
                    t = self.vertex[u]
                else:
                    break
                a = t.keys()
                for u in a:
                    if u not in visited:
                        stac.append(u)
        return False
```

My main function:

```
def main():

g = Graph(10)
g.insert_edge(0,1,5.0)
g.insert_edge(0,2,10.0)
g.insert_edge(1,3,3.0)
g.insert_edge(1,4,6.0)
g.insert_edge(3,2,2.0)
g.insert_edge(3,4,2.0)
g.insert_edge(3,5,2.0)
g.insert_edge(4,6,6.0)
g.insert_edge(5,6,2.0)
g.insert_edge(7,9,1.0)
g.insert_edge(8,7,2.0)
g.insert_edge(8,9,4.0)

print(g.vertex)
print(g.does_path_exist(2,3)) #returns False but should return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop **only examines outgoing edges**. If you give it `u=2`, it finds no outgoing edges from `2`, and so it ends after one iteration.

You need to either:

1. Add directed edges in both directions in `insert_edge()`. This is a bit more work in `insert_edge()`, and some more memory usage.
2. Search the vertex dictionary for backwards edges in the loop as well as forward ones. This is significantly more computation in `does_edge_exist()`.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. My graph class is already an un-directed graph (without any direction) and my depth first search function does_path_exist() is built for a directed graph. I would like to build that function for a un-directed class. I'll make an edit to my question.

Comment: To be honest, the simplest way to do that is to leave `does_edge_exist()` as-is and add two directed edges for every undirected edge - my point (1), above.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the graph is an directed graph but you only assign edge from `u` to `v` in the `insert_edge` function. I updated the function so that it will also assign edge from `v` to `u` and it returned `True` for the test input.

```
    def insert_edge(self, u, v, w): #works fine
        # Allow to travel from u to v
        if u in self.vertex and v < self.order:
            if not v in self.vertex[u]:
                self.vertex[u][v] = w
                self.size += 1
        elif u not in self.vertex and u < self.order and v < self.order:
            self.vertex[u] = {}
            self.vertex[u][v] = w
            self.size += 1
        else:
            raise IndexError

        # Allow travel to v from u
        if v in self.vertex and u < self.order:
            if not u in self.vertex[v]:
                self.vertex[v][u] = w
        elif v not in self.vertex and v < self.order and u < self.order:
            self.vertex[v] = {}
            self.vertex[v][u] = w
        else:
            raise IndexError
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. My graph class is already an un-directed graph (without any direction) and my depth first search function does_path_exist() is built for a directed graph. I would like to build that function for a un-directed class. I'll make an edit to my question.